# MonoGame ortho projection axis direction

Tags: monogame, projection

I have perfect square screen and I want to capture everything between -1000.0f and 1000.0f, so I create projection matrix like that:

```
var proj = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(left: -width,
                                              right: width, 
                                              bottom: -height,
                                              top: height, 
                                              zNearPlane: -1.0f, 
                                              zFarPlane: 1.0f);
```

I expect the axes to be X - left >>> right and Y down >>> up, but if I project some points with `Vector2.Transform` I get following:

```
(-1000, -1000) is (-1, -1)
(1000, 1000) is (1, 1)
```

I expect -1 on Y axis to be the top of the screen, but it is actually the bottom. How so? Is there some convention I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGL and DirectX coordinate systems are traditional cartesian coordinate systems. (0, 0) is in the center, the positive x direction is to the right and the positive y direction is to up.

[image]